# is it ok to cache some API results in redis permanently?

Tags: caching, redis, denormalization

Some APIs (that may be increase about 1000000 * users count) and each of them has only 1 integer value are very time consuming so I decided to cache them in redis but I found that if I have a expiration mechanism so I have to fallback to mysql to get result every time redis doesn't have a result. (in fact the case of null result is more probable than having an integer value at least in start of the project so if I do not store null values, app will hit mysql many times for null values.)

So I decided to use redis as "growing cache". 
It means that I should save all none zero (or not null) value in redis permanently. I am hesitated is it a good practice or we should choose redis as a temporary cache with an expiration mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

well, you cannot keep an ever growing redis, as you have a limited amount of memory. So I would advise to take those steps:

- try to evaluate the minimum number of keys that you need to have a useful cache
- translate that into a memory need. See if fits within your available total memory
- then you must think about your expiration mechanism. The usual one is LRU, in which you delete the oldest keys.

I don't really understand your issue with null values at the beginning, because it seems that you still need to do the app call at least once for each query at the start of the process, I don't see how you could avoid it (having 0 in redis will result in answering always 0 and never calling the actual app, right ?)

Comment: we store only none zero values in redis and save none zero values during write operations not read operations (we use redis as a denormalized data not a cache and every time something changed we update related denormalized data in redis)

Comment: as I know redis has a feature to scale horizontally (clustering) so we can use multiple nodes to handle memory limits.

Comment: you very mush should look into the memory need, it is possibly surprisingly small...